# VB Script in excel to separate a paragraph in lines of 38

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am working on taking a paragraph and separating that paragraph out in lines of 38 characters. What I was thinking was having a button for the employee to click and it will grab the information out of a certain cell, and place it in a text box of numerous lines that only have 38 characters, so the employee then can copy and paste it in our ERP system.  The other kicker is I need a hard return after each line for it to probably be copied over.  I was trying to use Str.Substring.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Please post what code you have so far. There is nothing here to work with.

Comment: Str.Substring is VB.Net not VBA, VBScript or Excel-VBA.  Use Mid(String)

Comment: Not sure how the Mid(String) would work.  But I am trying the Break_String().  This is what i have so far.  Struggling on how I would call a certain cell in exel and how to split after 38 characters.         Sub Break_String()
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim text_string =
WrdArray () = Split(text_string)

For I = LBound(WrdArray) to UBound(WrdArray)
Strg = strg & vbNewLine  & “Line ” & i & “ - “ & WrdArray(i)
Next i
MsgBox strg
End Sub

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Please edit your question and post the code there.

Comment: You may also need to figure out how to wrap lines with a max length of 38, unless you are willing to split "words." A much harder task. Are you sure the destination program can't do the wrapping for you?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to take a paragraph and break it into a series of 38 character lines, separated by hard line breaks. The following code does so to the first cell in the worksheet (A1) and puts the clipboard, so all your users have to do is paste.

```
Sub main()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Output As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim inputString As String
    inputString = Cells(1, 1)
    'We're going to go through the input string
    'one character at a time
    For x = 1 To Len(inputString)
        'Each time through, we add one to our counter
        counter = counter + 1
        'When the counter reaches our breakpoint
        If counter = 38 Then
            'add a hard carriage return and line feed
            Output = Output & vbCrLf
            'Reset our counter
            counter = 0
        End If
        'Append the current letter to the output
        Output = Output & Mid(inputString, x, 1)
    Next

    'This puts the output string in the clipboard.
    'You need to have a userform in your project for this to work
    'or a reference to MSForms.
    Dim cb As New DataObject
    cb.SetText Output
    cb.PutInClipboard
    'This cleans up the clipboard object
    Set cb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a word wrap function that breaks the input string by space (replacing any new line characters) and fills the lines with *whole words* up to the specified margin. Unit tests attached to demonstrate typical usage.

```
Function getWordWrap(str As String, Optional margin As Long = 78) As String

    Dim tokenArr() As String
    Dim token As Variant
    Dim line As String
    Dim numChars As Long

    tokenArr = Split(Replace(str, vbNewLine, " "))
    For Each token In tokenArr
        ' if above margin - start a new line
        If numChars > 0 And numChars + Len(token) + 1 > margin Then
            getWordWrap = getWordWrap & Trim(line) & vbNewLine
            numChars = 0: line = ""
        End If
        line = line & token & " "
        numChars = Len(line) - 1
    Next
    getWordWrap = getWordWrap & Trim(line)

End Function


Sub testGetWordWrap()

    ' basic tests
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui.", 15) = "Illum rerum" & vbNewLine & "qui."
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("", 15) = ""
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui quia sequi excepturi adipisci iure.", 15) _
            = "Illum rerum qui" & vbNewLine & "quia sequi" & vbNewLine & "excepturi" _
                    & vbNewLine & "adipisci iure."

    ' very long words
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("VeryVeryLongWord", 15) = "VeryVeryLongWord"
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui. VeryVeryLongWord", 15) _
            = "Illum rerum" & vbNewLine & "qui." & vbNewLine & "VeryVeryLongWord"
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui. VeryVeryLongWord quia sequi", 15) _
            = "Illum rerum" & vbNewLine & "qui." & vbNewLine & "VeryVeryLongWord" _
                    & vbNewLine & "quia sequi"

    ' pre-existing new lines
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui quia sequi" & vbNewLine & "excepturi adipisci iure.", 15) _
            = "Illum rerum qui" & vbNewLine & "quia sequi" & vbNewLine & "excepturi" _
                    & vbNewLine & "adipisci iure."

    ' different margins
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui.", 1) = "Illum" & vbNewLine & "rerum" & vbNewLine & "qui."
    Debug.Assert getWordWrap("Illum rerum qui.", 20) = "Illum rerum qui."

End Sub
```